# kendo grid ajax is firing before data property of ajax is initilized. Which results in null data to be submitted to server

Tags: kendo-ui

When I am doing crud operations in kendo ui grid,
grid's ajax is firing before data property of ajax is initilized. 
Which results in null data to be submitted to server.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the automatic request with **[autobind](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#autobind-booleandefault)** option set to false and manually call the read ajax request.

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried the solution you mentioned. When adding new data still I have same problem. Rows are submitted to server with null value assigned in it. Is it possible to disable automatic create operation. Or I need to remove create call and do it manually as you mentioned.

Comment: It is not possible to disable automatic create and yes you can do it manually with the dataSource.create() operation.

Comment: @Pechka, not sure what Kiren Siva means by _automatic_ and what you mean by _not possible to disable automatic create_ . You can write your own `create` function in `transport` and do there whatever you want.